# same httppost function in MVC Controller and MVC ControllerBase, but error find in ControllerBase

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I create the web MVC Core project and have two controller,
where main controller is controller and sessiondatacontroller is controllerbase
I place the same function as below

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<SessionInfo> GetSessionInfo(string SessionID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Main.GetSessionInfo({SessionID})");
            var getSession = await SessionService.GetSessionInfoAsync(int.Parse(SessionID));
            if (getSession == null) return null;
            return new()
            {
                returnstartdate = getSession.dtStartTime.HasValue ? getSession.dtStartTime.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss") : string.Empty,
                returnenddate = getSession.dtEndTime.HasValue ? getSession.dtEndTime.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss") : string.Empty
            };

        }
```

For view, in Javascript
I call the function  as below

```
function cbSessionChange() {
       
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetSessionInfo", "SessionData")'; 

        var selectvalue = $("#cbSessionList").val(); // Confirm have value
        console.log(`cbSessionList.val : ` + selectvalue.toString())

        $.post(url, { SessionID :selectvalue.toString()},
            function (data) {

                $('#txtDateFr').val(data.returnstartdate);
                $('#txtDateTo').val(data.returnenddate);

            }
        ,'json')
    };
```

If I call GetSessionInfo(SessionID) in Controller is work, however, I get null parameter value when call GetSessionInfo(SessionID) in ControllerBase.
However, I try to use postman to test this two function are both working.

Can I know any wrong inside?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` method default content type is `application/x-www-url-formencoded`.

If your ControllerBase declares with `[ApiController]` attribute, it causes model binding system binds the data **from body**  (content type is `application/json`)by default.

To achieve your requirement, specific `[FromForm]` attribute in your ControllerBase:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<SessionInfo> GetSessionInfo([FromForm]string SessionID)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

Or just remove `[ApiController]`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
//[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<SessionInfo> GetSessionInfo(string SessionID)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to post `application/json` data by ajax, change like below:

```
<script>
function cbSessionChange() {

    var url = '@Url.Action("GetSessionInfo", "SessionData")';
    var selectvalue = 1; // Confirm have value
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(selectvalue.toString()),   //add this..
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
            $('#txtDateFr').val(result.returnstartdate);
            $('#txtDateTo').val(result.returnenddate);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public class SessionDataController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<SessionInfo>  GetSessionInfo([FromBody] string SessionID)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: hi , but I try to change the code into $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                $('#txtDateFr').val(result.returnstartdate);
                $('#txtDateTo').val(result.returnenddate);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
            }
        });
is also get null error

Comment: Hi @Emily, I have updated my answer, please check.